# Firebase Function shutdown requested via /__/quitquitquit Functions codebase could not be analyzed successfully. It may have a syntax or runtime error

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to deploy my functions. I added a second one and refactored the first and now I can't deploy. I tried deploying manually bypassing CI/CD but it still is giving the error. This is a 2.0 function and I did run tsc. Since I last deployed I did reinstall the firebase-tools package. Other than what I mentioned, nothing is different from when it did work.

Here are the output of `firebase deploy --only functions`:

```
i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint

> lint
> eslint --ext .js,.ts .

Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run build

> build
> tsc

✔  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
i  functions: preparing codebase default for deployment
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  artifactregistry: ensuring required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled...
✔  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  artifactregistry: required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: Loading and anaylzing source code for codebase default to determine what to deploy
Serving at port 8907

shutdown requested via /__/quitquitquit


Error: Functions codebase could not be analyzed successfully. It may have a syntax or runtime error
```

And my code:

```
/* eslint-disable max-len */
import "dotenv/config";
import { initializeApp } from "firebase-admin/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase-admin/firestore";
import { onDocumentCreated, onDocumentDeleted } from "firebase-functions/v2/firestore";

const accountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
const authToken = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;
const twilioPhoneNumber = process.env.TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER;

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires
const client = require("twilio")(accountSid, authToken);

export const sendSMSOnContactWrite = onDocumentCreated("/contact/{contactSubmissionId}", async (event) => {
  const data = event.data?.data();
  console.log(data);
  return await client.messages.create({
    // eslint-disable-next-line
    "body": `New contact submission from ${data?.name} at ${data?.email} with message: ${data?.message}. ${data?.name} said ${data?.hasWebsite} when asked if they have a website.${data?.hasWebsite === "yes" ? " Their website is at " + data?.websiteAddress : ""}`,
    "from": twilioPhoneNumber,
    "to": process.env.MY_PHONE_NUMBER,
  });
});

export const sendSMSOnContentItemDelete = onDocumentDeleted("/websites/{websiteId}/content/{contentGroupId}/data/{contentId}", async (event) => {
  initializeApp();
  const db = getFirestore();
  const websiteDocRef = db.doc("websites/" + event.params.websiteId);
  const websiteDoc = await websiteDocRef.get();
  const websiteDocData = websiteDoc.data();
  if (!websiteDocData) {
    // TODO: Log error
    return;
  }
  const users = websiteDocData["users"];
  for (const userId of users) {
    const userDocRef = db.doc("users/" + userId);
    const userDoc = await userDocRef.get();
    const userDocData = userDoc.data();
    if (!userDocData) {
      // TODO: Log error
      return;
    }
    const deletionPreference = userDocData["preferences"]["deletion_sms"];
    if (deletionPreference) {
      const data = event.data?.data();
      console.log(data);
      return await client.messages.create({
        "body": `Content item with title ${data?.title} was deleted from website ${websiteDocData["url"]}`,
        "from": twilioPhoneNumber,
        "to": userDocData["phone_number"],
      });
    } else {
      return;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Add import `twilo` like this `import twilio from 'twilio;` and You need to replace client twilio i.e., this line `const client = require("twilio")(accountSid, authToken);` with `const client = twilio(accountSid, authToken);`

Answer (score 15):

It can be caused by different things, to know precisely what the issue is for your case, run with the `--debug` option.

So it will result in something like `firebase deploy --only functions --debug`

Then check the last paragraph before the message ***Error: Functions codebase could not be analyzed successfully***

Hope it will help.

Comment: If you are using emulators to test the functions locally first, use this command to debug `firebase emulators:start --debug`

Comment: Because there are so many different reasons you could be receiving this error, this answer is actually the most accurate and should be accepted as the answer.

Comment: This helped me. After running the debug it showed me I just needed to run an update of firebase tools.

Answer (score 9):

In my case, I had to move `const firestore = admin.firestore();` inside the function instead of having it outside the function.

Comment: Similar thing. Had to move `initializeApp();` inside.

Comment: This is the solution in my case.

Comment: How do you move initializeApp() inside a function?
I have like 60+ functions.

Answer (score 3):

If you're working with Cloud Functions of Gen 2:

Check if you're you're using `onRequest()` Function correctly. I got the same error because i declared my function wrong.

Do `exports.functionName = onRequest((data, context) => { ...`
instead of `exports.functionName = functions.onRequest((data, context) => { ...`

and import it via `const {onRequest} = require("firebase-functions/v2/https");`

Answer (score 3):

In my case, it was slack bolt api.

```
const { App, ExpressReceiver } = require('@slack/bolt');
const app = new App({
    token: process.env.SLACK_BOT_TOKEN,
    signingSecret: process.env.SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET,
});
```

This code should work without error if deployed since the parameters were set as secrets

```
firebase functions:secrets:set SECRET_NAME
```

However it seems like `firebase deploy` failed to apply those secrets during codebase analysis, thus the bolt App crashes not having required parameters.

My solution is to use local `.env`, just to pass the analysis,

```
const { App, ExpressReceiver } = require('@slack/bolt');
require('dotenv').config();

const app = new App({
    token: process.env.SLACK_BOT_TOKEN,
    signingSecret: process.env.SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET,
});
```

but to exclude it from deploying in `firebase.json`.

```
   "ignore": [
        ".env",
   ]
```

Comment: This answer helps me. In helper functions, you will need to use dotenv because firebase automatically don't add the env variables to process.env object.

Answer (score 3):

### General Troubleshooting Approach

1. Try to start the Firebase emulators using `firebase emulators:start`
2. When this fails, a new `firebase-debug.log` file will be created at the root of your project
3. Open `firebase-debug.log` and scroll to the bottom to find the error

### Popular Issues

- You are using a [reserved Firebase key](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env?gen=2nd#reserved-names) in your .env file
- You are using `export const myFunction` instead of `exports.myFunction`
- [You are trying to use process.env.PORT in your express app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70631543/cant-serve-express-app-on-firebase-functions-emulator-eaddrinuse-address-alr) (PORT is a reserved .env name)

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was on NodeJS v20.0.0 while using `firebase-tools` <= 12.4.4

Previously, I tried Node v19.5.0 while using `firebase-tools` <= 12.4.4 and I was able to deploy with no errors.

Today, I tried using NodeJS v20.0.0 and installed `npm install firebase-tools@12.4.5 --save`. No more deploy errors on my end.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the Firebase Function might be experiencing difficulties due to an improper initialization. To resolve this issue, I suggest you initialize your Firebase app globally in the index.js file.

You should add the following code to your index.js:

```
// Initialize Firebase app globally:
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

if (admin.apps.length === 0) {
  admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
}
```

The above code snippet checks if any Firebase apps have been initialized. If not (`admin.apps.length === 0`), it initializes the app using the Firebase config.

In addition, you should also ensure that your function initializes Firebase if it hasn't been initialized globally. You can accomplish this by adding the following code to your function:

```
if (admin.apps.length === 0) {
  admin.initializeApp();
}
```

By taking these steps, you're making sure that your Firebase Function doesn't get shut down due to a lack of proper initialization.

Answer (score 1):

We have found a solution and the cause: accessing function config params at deploy time.

Apparently they can only be accessed at runtime, not deploy time. Moving those accesses inside the actual function code makes things work again.

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue it was caused by third-party imports

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch'
```

I've got the exact same error when I was using node-fetch.I solved my problem by downgrading the node-fetch from version 3 to version 2. It turns out that I imported the node-fetch with require() for the v3 node-fetch, while v3 is a ESM-only module.

```
npm install node-fetch@2
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, I was getting the error because I was importing:

```
import {onDocumentCreated} from "firebase-functions/lib/v2/providers/firestore";
```

Fixed with:

```
import {onDocumentCreated} from "firebase-functions/v2/firestore";
```

Comment: ily <3<3<3<3<3<3

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue because I mistakenly exported other variables and functions in addition to 'onRequest' in Firebase Functions. I suspect that firebase-tools analyzes all the data exported by developers. So, if you're facing the same error, you can try removing those exports and see if it resolves the issue.

For example when I use it with trpc, it throws above error:

```
import { initTRPC } from "@trpc/server";
import { createHTTPHandler } from "@trpc/server/adapters/standalone";
import { onRequest } from "firebase-functions/v1/https";

const t = initTRPC.create();

// How to fix: don't export appRouter, just define it and use it
// if you want to export appRouter, 
// I think you can use another file to do it instead of using src/index.ts file
export const appRouter = t.router({
  Hi: t.procedure.query(() => {
    return { data: "hi" };
  }),
});

export const v0 = onRequest(
  createHTTPHandler({
    router: appRouter,
    createContext: () => {
      return {};
    },
  }),
);
```